# Spotfire Average over the data points on a scatter plot

Tags: spotfire

I have a scatter plot that has a bunch of points, which are averages on the interval on a certain column( each average would have a varying number of data points that make up the average for that interval). I created a separate calculated column to to find me the average over the timespan, but this is giving me more like a weighted average rather than the average of the points on the graph. ie its taking all 1000 rows and averaging them accordingly but i want it to average the averages displayed on the chart. any ideas?

screen shot of chart below

you can see the average line says its 4.35 but if you take an average of all the point then its 4.26

is there a way to make it show me of the averages charted instead of the weighted way it tis doing
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OundK.png)

Comment: The average of averages is not the same as the average of the original points. So I think the weighted average would actually be the right answer.

Comment: I agree, but that's not what I was tasked to find